# Making a home page without /home

Tags: 7, nodes

My website is mycapecodvacations.com I need help how to make the default home page mycapecodvacations.com instead of going to mycapecodvacations.com/home I'm using host gator .com and want to know how to make the home page without /home and just " mycapecodvacations.com" i tried removing the htaccess file. do I need to edit a specific file?

Comment: Just a thought. What is path of your home page? This you can find at Configuration>Site information>Front page.

Comment: the path is http://mycapecodvacations.com/home/

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Comment: If it is D7, just remove /home part and leave it blank, and check whether it is working.

Comment: it didn't fix it

Comment: Might be issue with your file location. Previous day I was googling for this issue and found this link http://www.thesitewizard.com/faqs/default-page-after-publishing.shtml, It may work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module.

> Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and
>   redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.

Every time when mycapecodvacations.com/home is accessed, Global Redirect will redirect to mycapecodvacations.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to: **admin/config/system/site-information**

Then leave in blank the **Deafult Homepage**

And if you want to customize your homepage HTML, you can create a new TPL (You just need to place it where your main **page.tpl.php** is) called:

**page--front.tpl.php**